# Get values of parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, location

I’m working on a tool which takes the value parameters in the URL and does a few things with them.

My issue is, I can’t seem to use document.location to show the specific value  that I’m after, for example:

`www.examplesite.com?yourname=gilgilad`

I want to use `document.location.search` and put it in a var, I need that var's value to be "gilgilad".

Is this even possible using `location.search`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`location.search` will return all after question mark including it. So there is universal js to get value of the first parameter (even if url has more parameters):

```
var desire = location.search.slice(1).split("&")[0].split("=")[1]
```

**Example**: let's take url `http://example.com?name=jon&country=us`

1. `location.search` will be equal to `?name=jon&country=us`
2. `.slice(1)` skips the `?`, returning the rest of the string.
3. `.split("&")[0]` splits it into two strings (`name=jon` and
   `country=us`) and takes first one
4. `.split("=")[1]` splits `name=jon` into `name` and `jon` and takes the second one. Done!

Comment: This is a good answer, especially considering that it goes over the fact that search grabs everything after the url including the question mark.

Comment: @MatthewA.McFarland Wait. Now I don't really understand the question. Did he mean to read or to set location.search, how do you think?

Comment: nicael, I think he meant to set when he said "put in a var"

Comment: Quick one-liner to get a specific parameter ('referrer' here): `new Map(window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(q => q.split('='))).get('referrer')`

Answer (score 6):

```
let url = new URL('www.examplesite.com?yourname=gilgilad');
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
console.log(searchParams.get('yourname'));
```

you can consider also to user `window.location` or `window.location.search` directly

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(searchParams.get('yourname'));
```

Answer (score 3):

A more generic solution to split the location.search query parameters and convert them into an object:

```
var a = location.search.split("&");
var o = a.reduce(function(o, v) {
    var kv = v.split("=");
    kv[0] = kv[0].replace("?", "");
    o[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    return o;
    },
{});
```

Answer (score -2):

To make `?yourname=gilgilad` using document.location.search:

```
window.location.search = 'yourname=gilgilad';
```

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t81k3bgc/

make sure to use console and then `[run]`. you will see: 
[image]

For more information: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location#Example_.235.3A_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property.3A