# window.location is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-on-rails

When I load the home page of my react-redux application I got the error

> Encountered error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of
>   undefined" when prerendering App with
>   {"location":"/","currency":"USD"}

I am getting error in following code

```
const UrlParser = {

getQueryVariable: (variable) => {
  let query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  let vars = query.split('&');
  for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    let pair = vars[i].split('=');
    if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) === variable) {
      return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      }
    }
  }
}

export default UrlParser;
```

can anyone please help me

Edit

window.location on console gives

> ```
>     Location {href: "http://localhost:5000/", ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "http://localhost:5000", replace: function,
> ```
>
> assign: function…}
>       ancestorOrigins:DOMStringListassign:function ()hash :"" host :
>       "localhost:5000"
>       hostname
>       :
>       "localhost"
>       href
>       :
>       "http://localhost:5000/"
>       origin
>       :
>       "http://localhost:5000"
>       pathname
>       :
>       "/"
>       port
>       :
>       "5000" protocol : "http:" reload : function reload() replace : function () search : "" toString : function toString() valueOf :
>   function valueOf() Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive) : undefined
>   **proto** : Location

Comment: Please detail the problem; at which line do you meet the error? with which input?

Comment: @pinturic let query = window.location.search.substring(1);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803253/6294260....please check this link if its helpful for you..

Comment: @Anish can you console.log(window.location) and tell us what you get?

Comment: @UrvishPatel in my problem it shows window.location it self isn't defined

Comment: @D-reaper pls see edits

Comment: You are using ReactDOMServer, yea?

Comment: @D-reaper i am using ReactDOM

Comment: I think the problem is not with window.location.search.substring(1), because it actually exists. Given what you have provided, my guess is that getQueryVariable may return undefined if decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) === variable never returns true. Can you return a default value at the end getQueryVariable? Let us know if this works

Comment: @D-reaper No the problem is in query=window.location.search.substring(1) ,because when i comment this line and pass query ="" ,it doesn't give error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much discussion, It's really hard to tell why assigning `window.location.search.substring(1)` throws an error. One way to circumvent this issue is by using a try catch clause:

```
getQueryVariable: (variable) => {

  let query;
  try {
    query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  } catch(e) {
    // window.location.search.substring(1) throws an error, set query
    // to fallback value ''
    console.log(e);
    query = '';
  }

  let vars = query.split('&');
  for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    let pair = vars[i].split('=');
    if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) === variable) {
      return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the try catch statement prevents the error from being thrown because it knows that you expects you to handle it within the catch statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 2):

To answer for the headline question title of **window.location is undefined** my wasted 20 minutes was because I was using the bad capitalization given here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

i.e. `Window.location` is wrong, `window.location` is correct.

Comment: Documentation at that link is for interface `Window` and as such is correct.  In the browser one instance named `window` exists.  Hence `window instanceof Window` is `true`.  In the browser `window` being the global object, examples given on that page simple write `location`, which then is `window.location` unless defined otherwise.

This can be confusing at first, but it has been consistently so and many of us got used to it :)